# new install of Ubuntu will not go past password login

Tags: login, password

I'm thoroughly frustrated with my Ubuntu 14.04 install. I wiped my Windows 7 in hopes that I would no longer need it  if Ubuntu was all it was purported to be. Now I'm screwed because Ubuntu will not allow me to get past the login prompt. And yes I used the right username and password. It simply is stuck in loop back to the login screen. I tried all I have patience for. Now I have an unusable machine. 
How can I uninstall Ubuntu and totally start over?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uninstall Ubuntu and install another OS or reinstall Ubuntu, you can just put in the installation material of the OS (USB, CD etc.) Then before the booting of Ubuntu begins you use the pre-defined button(s) to go into BIOS. (They differ between computers so I can't tell what buttons they are, but in most cases it prints it on screen when you start your computer up. Or you can Google it.) Set the boot options so the computer boots your installation material before booting OS. From there, you can install the OS of your choosing.

However if you didn't mean to go back to Windows by saying "totally starting over" then I think instead of performing a reinstall you can simply use recovery mode following the instructions from [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword) and get rid of your problem.

How you want to approach the situation is up to you.